Electromagnetic faraday tensor in Reissner-Nordström
I am trying to find an ansatz for the tensor $ A_\mu$ such that the non-zero elements of the electromagnetic tensor are $ F_{tr} = f(r)$and $F_{\theta \phi} = f(r) r^2 \sin \theta$.
I have tried different ansätze, such as $A_\mu = \left(\int f(r)  dr,  0,  0,  f(r) r^2 \int \sin \theta  d\theta \right)$. But I am getting additional terms and I am unable to reach the desired result.

For generic $f(r)$, $d F \neq 0$. Consequently, there is no $A$ such that $F=dA$.
